# Lost money from Revolut to Monese bank on 3 repetive transfers since 18.12.2023

Tags: transfer, sepa, revolut

Hi since 17th December 2023 I transferred from my private account Revolut to my other private account with Monese and still not arrived and Monese claims not having received my money claiming Revolut has to recall this from the intermediary bank .Credit Mutuel Arkea as the SEPA payments were in euro.

All previous transfers and the one later in December went well.

Revolut doesn’t seem to care at all, while for me this is an important amount and moreover they temporarily blocked my account “limited” as well- claiming security reasons as out of security I transferred 25% of my savings to another account of mine.

I m desperate … any thoughts and ideas how to solve this ?Thank you.

Comment: From what I can tell, neither Revolut nor Monese is actually a licensed bank, and they may not have the same consumer protections as real banks.

Answer (score 0):

If you told Revolut to transfer the money, they should have a record of where it was transferred to and whether that transfer succeeded. If it didn't, it's their responsibility to make sure the money lands back in your account with them. If it did, they should be able to trace the transfer and confirm that it reached Monese, and give you the tracking number.

You can then go to Monese and say this transfer, for this amount, was made on this date with this tracking number, and ask them where it went. You might have given them incorrect account information to transfer it to, or there may have been some other issue, but it's their responsibility to explain what happened and help you fix it.

Either one may need to pester the intermediate bank(s) for details. That shouldn't be a serious problem.

*Note* that this is assuming both accounts are real. If there's a scam in progress, your money (if it ever existed) may be long gone.

(General reminder: When moving money between accounts, it is always wise to try a small transfer first, to make sure you have entered all the data correctly. Most real banks will do this automatically the first time you attempt a transfer -- they will transfer a small amount and pull it back, then ask you to look at the other account's ledger and tell them what that amount was, as a 2FA/challenge-response test to be sure you gave the right account number and that it really is your account.)

Comment: Yes both accounts are real.Will ask for the transfer tracking number.
Thanks for your feedback.